# Node access based on condition

Tags: users

I'm adding an event list to a website and I want to limit what anonymous users see based on a field value, a checkbox "Private event". If the checkbox is marked then only a subset of the fields for the given event are shown. Furthermore, after a year of the event I want all fields to become visible to anonymous users. I took a look at the Access Control module but couldn't find a way to have this conditional type of access to fields. Is there another module that I could use?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is too localized for a module with general application. You should look, instead, at putting your logic into a preprocess function to hide or show the fields based on your logic. Have a look at [Setting up variables for use in a template](https://drupal.org/node/223430) for a starting point.

Comment: @Triskelion It doesn't quite feel right to me to put this in the theme. Sure, usually a site only runs a single theme, but lets say you have one mobile and one 'normal' theme, then you'd have to re-implement this logic in both themes. It feels like this is to much logic/site functionality to be in the presentation layer.

Comment: @Letharion Good point. Only the last two layers of preprocess are theme-specific so it could probably be set up as a module_preprocess function. That way it would apply to all themes. However, I like your approach below.

Comment: @Triskelion Ah, you're right of course, I just read template and thought of the theme. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

1. Define a new 'Restricted' View mode. Either manually with [hook_entity_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7) or with [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds).
2. Create a new `Page` in [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), using the by default available `Node view`.
3. Create two separate `variants` in the page.

   1. The first one will use a selection rule on ´Role: Anonymous´ and ´Field Private event: True´. In this `Variant`, display the node with the 'Restricted' view mode.
   2. The second variant will not need a selection rule, as it will be the fall through option. Here you show the node with the normal 'Full' view mode.

For making everything visible after a year , it sounds like either a [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) with some code in it, or perhaps a combination of some [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) with a [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), which would flip the private field off after a year. Sounds like that might be a separate question though.

Comment: Could the selection rule not also test the date, eliminating the need to alter the Field Private Event?

Comment: It absolutely could, but last time I checked the generic per field access checks weren't sophisticated enough to do something like comparing dates, so I believe that would require a custom access plugin. (Or a patch to ctools)

Comment: Hi Letharion, thanks for fast reply. If I do what you suggested does this mean that I will have to basically maintain two pages, one for logged in users and another one for anonymous ones?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking. Technically, you'd be maintaining two "View modes", to differentiate the rendering, and two "Variants", to tell Drupal when to use which rendering. I don't know if that answers your question or not. There's no duplication of work or code, if that's what you mean.