# Result accessibility based on field value for specific group

Tags: users

Is there a way to hide nodes or results if it has field "restricted" type bool with value 1 if the logged in user not in admin group without writing custom code.
i could do that with views hooks like "hook_views_post_execute" with writing custom code but it will decrease the performance because i will load the node field in "foreach", so is there module can handle that from the back end !?

Comment: You can use `hook_node_access`. The node is already loaded for inspection there.

Answer (score 0):

The [field permissions module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) lets you assign permissions to individual fields.

[image]

Comment: Yes i know, but this just hide or display the field while i want to hide or display the whole content or node.

Comment: Oh I see, does this help?
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83567/node-access-based-on-condition?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This helped me better as its global solution for the view i want to hook.

```
function rcreee_helper_views_post_execute(&$view){
$views_name = array('country_profile_item_energy_efficiency',
                    'country_profile_item_renewable_energy',
                    'country_profile_item_fuel_prices',
                    'country_profile_item_power_sector',
                    'country_profile_item_energy_system_overview'
                    );
$restricted_groups = array(3=>'administrator',9=>'Premium Registered');
global $user, $restricted_groups;
$has_access = count(array_intersect_key($restricted_groups , $user->roles));
if($has_access<=0){
    if(in_array($view->name,$views_name)){
        foreach ($view->result as $result_k => $result_v){

            if(isset($result_v->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_visibility)
                && $result_v->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_visibility['und'][0]['value']==1)
            {
                unset($view->result[$result_k]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Just a few words of warning about this approach: 1. it won't work properly with paging; 2. it might be neater to use a permission rather than a hard-coded list of roles, to make it easier to update; 3. the nodes are only hidden for these views, there may be plenty of other "security holes" on your site letting the user see premium content. A more complete but more complicated way to solve the problem is using Drupal's built-in [node access system](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/7).